# Find the matrix $A$ such that the following is true:$ T_1(T_2(\mathbf{x})) = A\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image: Linear transformation problem]

I found a matrix for $\mathbf{x} = (1, 1)$, and then took the $T_2$ transformation then the $T_1$, but it wasn't correct. I don't really understand what they're asking for me. Should I be finding the transformation of just variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of actual numbers? Also, I can change the dimensions of the answered matrix.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Simply use the result of $T_2$ as input in $T_1$ and calculate the result.

Comment: Let $x_1 = [1, 0]^T$, $x_2 = [0, 1]^T$. $T_1(T_2(x_i)), i = 1, 2$ will be the $i$th column of $A$

Answer (score 1):

look at what $$T_1\left(T_2\pmatrix{1\\0}\right) = T_1\pmatrix{-2\\0} =\pmatrix{-6\\4} \tag 1$$  i will let you work through $$T_1\left(T_2\pmatrix{0\\1}\right)= \pmatrix{a\\b}\tag2  $$

once you have $(1)$ and $(2),$  you can write $$T_1\left(T_2\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}\right) = \pmatrix{-6x_1+ax_2\\4x_1+bx_2}=A\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$$ where $$A=\pmatrix{-6&a\\4&b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**:- If $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are Linear Transformations with matrices $[T_{1}]$ , $[T_{2}]$ . Then the Matrix of the transformation $T_{1}\circ T_{2}$ is given by $[T_{1}]\cdot[T_{2}]$.
And conversely, if the matrix of a linear transformation $T$ is given by $[T_{1}]\cdot [T_{2}]$ . Then $T=T_{1}\circ T_{2}$

So now just find out the matrices of $[T_{1}]$ , $[T_{2}]$ and multiply them out to get $A$. I will do it in terms of standard ordered bases. You can also do it for any basis of $\mathbb{F^{2}}$.

We have $T_{1}(1,0)=(3,-2)=3(1,0)-2(0,1)$
$T_{1}(0,1)=(5,6)=5(1,0)+6(0,1)$.

So $[T_{1}]=\begin{bmatrix} 3&5\\-2&6\end{bmatrix}$.

Similarly $[T_{2}]=\begin{bmatrix}-2&9\\0&5\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $A=[T_{1}]\cdot[T_{2}]=\begin{bmatrix} -6&52\\4&12\end{bmatrix}$ .